# Adding wordpress functionality to parts of a client's website

Tags: php, wordpress

I have client who's website I'll be redoing in the next few months.
I've been programming in PHP for years, and I've been using wordpress for years, but I've never dabbled much in wordpress's code, or made use of "The Loop".

Just wondering: is it possible to create their website normally, but also have a wordpress installation present on the server to allow the customer to post/edit things to just one or two specific pages of the site?

Is the best option in this case to just create the whole site as a wordpress site with a custom theme, or is it possible to just pull in posts where necessary on a regular php site?

OR is there another better option available I'm unaware of?
Thanks for any info!

Comment: it depends what that site is going to be capable of...

Comment: on thing i have done multiple times in the past is to have a regular site, then install wordpress into a subdirectory such as `/blog` then styled WP install to match with the regular site, this allows them to post/edit blog through wordpress but not have access to the entire site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic way of doing this (as celeriko points out in a comment) is to install Wordpress in a `blog` directory and run your blog through Wordpress.  However, you can do what you have requested too, it's a regular thing for Magento developers as the Wordpress admin is much easier for clients to add static content to and for me to customise.

There are lots of ways of doing it but the method I have been using recently is to install a JSON API plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/ into the Wordpress install and use that to pull content from the Wordpress install into other parts of the site.

To give you a code example - the code below pulls the requisite entries in Wordpress for a custom post type called `event`, accesses a custom field in those posts called `eventdate` puts them all in an array, sorts it by date and outputs a list of all the events with a link to each event page in Wordpress install.

```
<ul>
    <?php 

    $events = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://www.mydomain.com/blog/?json=get_posts&post_type=event'));

    $eventList = array();

    foreach ( $events->posts as $event_item ) :

        $arrayDate = date("ymdHi", strtotime($event_item->custom_fields->eventdate[0] ));

        $eventList[$arrayDate]['Title'] = $event_item->title;
        $eventList[$arrayDate]['Date'] = date('l jS F', strtotime($event_item->custom_fields->eventdate[0] ));
        $eventList[$arrayDate]['Link'] = $event_item->url;


    endforeach; 

    // Key reverse sort to get events in date order
    ksort($eventList);

    foreach ($eventList as $eventItem) : 

        echo '<li><a href="'. $eventItem['Link'] .'">'. $eventItem['Title'] .' - '. $eventItem['Date'] .'</a></li>';

    endforeach;     

    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: The JSON API sounds like what I'm after. I sort of just want to have A page where the client can post things, not necessarily a full blog. Thanks!

Comment: I think your idea is good, there's a lot to be said for using Wordpress as the CMS just because its so easy for clients to use/pick up and super easy to develop with (and loads of online resource to help you customise it.). If you are new to WP have a look at http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/meta-box/ . And in terms of Json I am also keen to try this - http://thermal-api.com

Comment: Wordpress v4 supposed to have an API but nice one on the Thermal plugin McNab, didn't know of that one, only DPhiffer JSON api.

Comment: @LBarker - Ah, I didn't know about the WP v4 API.  Thanks for adding that too! :)

Answer (score 0):

The choice of how to implement WordPress will mainly depend on the requirements of your site. But if you use WordPress for just editing pages then you'll be defeating its purpose.

If WordPress is too much for you, there are tons of other CMS which are lightweight and have small learning curve. They might fit the purpose your trying to achieve. Below is a list of some of them.

[Anchor CMS](http://anchorcms.com/)

[Pico CMS](http://picocms.org/)

[Bolt CMS](http://bolt.cm/)

[Get Simple CMS](http://get-simple.info/)